# Media convert problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-media-convert

I am currently trying to transcode my set of videos through Amazon batch trancode but am having problems. My cloudwatch log output this error:

```
/var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: 
Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'tgzfwmguc.mediaconvert.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'. 
Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings /var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1013: 
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'tgzfwmguc.mediaconvert.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'. 
Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings.
```

My media convert job is showing this error.

```
Error message Unable to open input file s3://redacted/redacted.mp4: 
[Failed probe/open: [Can't read input stream: Failed to read data: 
HeadObject failed]] Error code 1404
```

Answer (score 0):

Those CloudWatch errors are warnings but will not stop the job from completing.

The second issue you mentioned is what is stopping the job. This is a permissions error when trying to access the file in the specified s3 bucket.

The 1404 error is explained here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/mediaconvert_error_codes.html

The basic theory is to ensure that [a] the named file exists; [b] the file has at least read access enabled from your AWS account; and [c] the  IAM Role assumed by MediaConvert when running jobs in your account has the Permissions Policy attached for 'AmazonS3FullAccess'.

Alternatively, you could generate a pre-signed URL for the file and use that as the input URL in the MediaConvert job.

Comment: Please do you mean public read access on the S3 bucket object.Thanks for the reply am grateful and thankful

Comment: Not public read access,  just read access from your AWS account.  If another account uploaded the object into your bucket, they may not have granted your account read access to the object.

Comment: Boss I uploaded the object to the bucket myself.I don't even know what is going on again.

Comment: Boss the 1404 error is still showing.I have enable read access.I cannot still get the error to go away

Comment: If you uploaded the object to the  bucket from your own account, then your account has access. I recommend checking the Role MediaConvert is assuming when running jobs for you, to confirm that Role has the necessary permissions as mentioned above.  
There may be additional info in your CloudTrail logs from the failed 'CreateJob' event re: details of the error.   

You can also try your job with this input file ( a public mp4) :  https://rodeolabz-us-west-2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/vodconsole/llama_drama.mp4 

This will tell you if you have a MediaConvert issue or an S3 issue.

Comment: @aws-robclem when using a presigned URL for the input file to MediaConvert, I get an issue because only GET or HEAD can be presigned but not both. MediaConvert requires both GET and HEAD methods to work.